# HorizontalScrollView with static images

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I want to create a HorizontalScrollView in my android app but i want my first and last image to be static and the rest of them should scroll. I can't seem to find any solution any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can simply set an horizontal layout, with 2 ImageViews and a HorizontalScrollView in the middle.